# TFS Prem Release No test assemblies found matching the pattern: **\*UITests*.dll,!**\obj\

Tags: automated-tests

I am trying to trigger tests to occur on our development environments servers.  The tests do get performed on the build server, which has the Build Agent and Test Agent.

On Our development server I have installed

- Test Agent
- I found this line [command]powershell NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy
  Unrestricted -file D:\TFSVSOWork_tasks So
- I copied that directory to the development server as it didn't
  exist.
- installed Chrome

I see in the log is

```
2019-07-11T20:11:46.5428863Z ##[section]Starting: VsTest - testAssemblies
2019-07-11T20:11:46.5428863Z ==============================================================================
2019-07-11T20:11:46.5428863Z Task         : Visual Studio Test
2019-07-11T20:11:46.5428863Z Description  : Run tests with Visual Studio test runner
2019-07-11T20:11:46.5428863Z Version      : 2.0.55
2019-07-11T20:11:46.5428863Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-07-11T20:11:46.5428863Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=835764)
2019-07-11T20:11:46.5428863Z ==============================================================================
2019-07-11T20:11:47.3085004Z Run the tests locally using vstest.console.exe
2019-07-11T20:11:47.3085004Z ========================================================
2019-07-11T20:11:47.3085004Z Test selector : Test assemblies
2019-07-11T20:11:47.3085004Z !**\obj\**
2019-07-11T20:11:47.3085004Z Test assemblies : **\*UITests*.dll,!**\obj\**
2019-07-11T20:11:47.3085004Z Test filter criteria : null
2019-07-11T20:11:47.3085004Z Search folder : D:\Applications\Http\xyz\test
2019-07-11T20:11:47.3241263Z Run settings file : D:\Applications\Http\Landing
2019-07-11T20:11:47.3241263Z Run in parallel : false
2019-07-11T20:11:47.3241263Z Run in isolation : false
2019-07-11T20:11:47.3241263Z Path to custom adapters : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow
2019-07-11T20:11:47.3241263Z Other console options : null
2019-07-11T20:11:47.3241263Z Code coverage enabled : false
2019-07-11T20:11:47.3241263Z VisualStudio version selected for test execution : latest
2019-07-11T20:11:47.3241263Z [command]powershell -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file D:\TFSVSOWork\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.0.55\vs15Helper.ps1
2019-07-11T20:11:48.2303716Z <Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
2019-07-11T20:11:48.2303716Z   <S>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise</S>
2019-07-11T20:11:48.2303716Z </Objs>
2019-07-11T20:11:48.2303716Z [command]wmic datafile where "name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TestWindow\\vstest.console.exe'" get Version /Value
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z 
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z 
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z 
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z 
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z Version=15.0.28307.421
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z 
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z 
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z 
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z 
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z 
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z 
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z 
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z 
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z 
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z 
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z Version=15.0.28307.421
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z 
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z 
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z 
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z 
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z 
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z 
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z 
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z 
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3397476Z ========================================================
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3553717Z ##[warning]No test assemblies found matching the pattern: **\*UITests*.dll,!**\obj\**.
2019-07-11T20:11:48.3709967Z ##[section]Finishing: VsTest - testAssemblies
```

Its not Failing the task, meaning I get a green check.  but I do get ##[warning]No test assemblies found matching the pattern: ***UITests*.dll,!**\obj**.
Or is there other pieces of software that I need still to load.

Answer (score 0):

> TFS Prem Release No test assemblies found matching the pattern: ***UITests*.dll,!**\obj\

By default we specify `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` as the search folder in the Visual Studio Test task. And this points to the Source folder on the Agent, which relevant to the directory where the Agent is installed.

But the search folder in your log is `D:\Applications\Http\xyz\test`, it seems the local folder on your TFS server. To resolve this issue, you should make sure **you are instructing MSBuild (using the OutDir parameter) to output your assemblies to that specific location when you build the project then you can use that location.**

Note: Since you test the assemblies at release, you should make sure those assemblies will not be cleaned up after the build is complete.

Update:

According to your Team Members`s error log, I found that following error message:

```
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9323329Z [command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe" \\Servername\D$\FAF_Applications\Http\XYZAppName\test\XYZAppName.Nunit.UITests.dll /logger:trx "/TestAdapterPath:\"D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a\"" /framework: .NetFramework,version=V4.7.2
2019-07-18T18:27:44.0417108Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.9.0
2019-07-18T18:27:44.1198351Z The /Framework argument requires the target .Net Framework version for the test run.   Example:  /Framework:".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1"
```

It seems you are not give the correct grammar rule in your parameters:

```
/framework: .NetFramework,version=V4.7.2
```

It should be:

```
/Framework:".NetFramework,version=V4.7.2"
```

You are missing the double quotes and add more space in the parameters.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No that doesn't help, sorry.  I understand $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) is pointing back to my build server, but now I am on the release server and I want to run my tests in the release environments. Do I need rebuild my code in the release environment with a build Agent and MSBuild on those set of servers to run tests? or should I be able to just run the tests? As I can see the test DLL's in D:\Applications\Http\xyz\test.

Comment: @StephanM, Thanks your reply. I got you now. You do not need to rebuild my code in the release environment with a build Agent and MSBuild. You just need copy all files in all `bin` folders of project to the folder `D:\Applications\Http\xyz\test` on your **development server**. And the important is that you should make sure the test agent can access that folder. As I test, I need add everyone with read/write permission, it works on my side.

Comment: we have found that The test cases on our Dev server can be triggered manually from cmd prompt and they all run successfully. But we had to enter the credentials manually in browser.  The same test cases wouldn’t be identified in Release pipeline. We do have the dll files in the Test folder, Also we gave read / write access to Everyone and gave it a shot. It didn’t work either.

Comment: @StephanM, I missed your reply prompt until I revisit my case. It seems your release pipeline do not have credentials  to access the dll file in the development server. Have you tried use the same account to login the development server and the release pipeline?

Comment: I have come to realize that you are also work with another one of my Team Members, so I will let you complete with him.  We do have .NetFramework, version=V4.7.2 installed.  I also added the DevPack, but still not working.

Comment: @StephanM, I am sorry that I replied so late because I am stuck in another mission. Then I check your Team Members`s error log with one word and one word, then I found something not correct, you can check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

As this doesn't answer all my questions it does answer How you get your tests to run someplace else other than the build server.  we had to load vstf_testagent.exe on the server that we wanted to test on.  From TFS we added a step to install vstf_testagent from the location that we put it.  We then started to see our test running and failing.  We have not figured out what needs to change as it is trying to run a specific version we can't find.