# Test assemblies run from command prompt but not from release pipeline, 'no test assemblies found matching the pattern' error

Tags: c#, automated-tests, integration-testing, azure-pipelines

Log from latest run; Trimmed down to keep it concise

```html
2019-07-18T18:27:42.9323100Z ##[section]Starting: VsTest - testAssemblies
2019-07-18T18:27:42.9323100Z Task         : Visual Studio Test
2019-07-18T18:27:42.9323100Z Description  : Run tests with Visual Studio test runner
2019-07-18T18:27:43.2448193Z ##[debug]agent.workFolder=D:\TFSVSOWork
2019-07-18T18:27:43.5104476Z ##[debug]System.DefaultWorkingDirectory=D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a
2019-07-18T18:27:43.6979545Z ##[debug]check path : D:\TFSVSOWork\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.0.55\task.json
2019-07-18T18:27:43.6979545Z ##[debug]set resource file to: D:\TFSVSOWork\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.0.55\task.json
2019-07-18T18:27:43.6979545Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
2019-07-18T18:27:43.6979545Z ##[debug]System.ParallelExecutionType=None
2019-07-18T18:27:43.6979545Z ##[debug]Value of ParallelExecutionType :None
2019-07-18T18:27:43.6979545Z ##[debug]testSelector=testAssemblies
2019-07-18T18:27:43.6979545Z ##[debug]Value of Test Selector :testAssemblies
2019-07-18T18:27:43.6979545Z ##[debug]testAssemblyVer2=XYZAppName.Nunit.UITests.dll
2019-07-18T18:27:43.6979545Z Test assemblies : XYZAppName.Nunit.UITests.dll
2019-07-18T18:27:43.6979545Z ##[debug]testFiltercriteria=null
2019-07-18T18:27:43.6979545Z Test filter criteria : null
2019-07-18T18:27:43.6979545Z ##[debug]searchFolder=\\Servername\D$\FAF_Applications\Http\XYZAppName\test
2019-07-18T18:27:43.6979545Z Search folder : \\Servername\D$\FAF_Applications\Http\XYZAppName\test
2019-07-18T18:27:43.6979545Z ##[debug]runSettingsFile=D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a
2019-07-18T18:27:43.6979545Z Run settings file : D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a
2019-07-18T18:27:43.6979545Z ##[debug]overrideTestrunParameters=null
2019-07-18T18:27:43.7135813Z ##[debug]runInParallel=false
2019-07-18T18:27:43.7135813Z Run in parallel : false
2019-07-18T18:27:43.7135813Z ##[debug]runTestsInIsolation=false
2019-07-18T18:27:43.7135813Z Run in isolation : false
2019-07-18T18:27:43.7135813Z ##[debug]runOnlyImpactedTests=false
2019-07-18T18:27:43.7135813Z ##[debug]wmic arg: ["datafile","where","name='C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\\\2017\\\\TestAgent\\\\Common7\\\\IDE\\\\Extensions\\\\TestPlatform\\\\vstest.console.exe'","get","Version","/Value"]
2019-07-18T18:27:43.7135813Z ##[debug]exec tool: wmic
2019-07-18T18:27:43.7135813Z ##[debug]Arguments:
2019-07-18T18:27:43.7135813Z ##[debug]   datafile
2019-07-18T18:27:43.7135813Z ##[debug]   where
2019-07-18T18:27:43.7135813Z ##[debug]   name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\TestAgent\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\TestPlatform\\vstest.console.exe'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.7135813Z ##[debug]   get
2019-07-18T18:27:43.7135813Z ##[debug]   Version
2019-07-18T18:27:43.7135813Z ##[debug]   /Value
2019-07-18T18:27:43.7135813Z [command]wmic datafile where "name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\TestAgent\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\TestPlatform\\vstest.console.exe'" get Version /Value
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z Version=15.0.0.0
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]VSTest Version information: 
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z Version=15.0.0.0
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]publishRunAttachments=true
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]vstest.ignoretestfailures=undefined
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ========================================================
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]TestRunResults Directory : D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a\TestResults
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]rm -rf D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a\TestResults
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]testing directory 'D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a\TestResults'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]testing directory 'D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]mkdir 'D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a\TestResults'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]Searching for test assemblies in: \\Servername\D$\FAF_Applications\Http\XYZAppName\test
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]defaultRoot: '\\Servername\D$\FAF_Applications\Http\XYZAppName\test'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSpecifiedSymbolicLink: 'true'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSymbolicLinks: 'true'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]matchOptions.debug: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nobrace: 'true'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]matchOptions.noglobstar: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]matchOptions.dot: 'true'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]matchOptions.noext: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nocase: 'true'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nonull: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]matchOptions.matchBase: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nocomment: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nonegate: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]matchOptions.flipNegate: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]pattern: 'XYZAppName.Nunit.UITests.dll'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]findPath: '\\Servername\D$\FAF_Applications\Http\XYZAppName\test\XYZAppName.Nunit.UITests.dll'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8073338Z ##[debug]statOnly: 'true'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]found 1 paths
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]applying include pattern
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]adjustedPattern: '\\Servername\D$\FAF_Applications\Http\XYZAppName\test\XYZAppName.Nunit.UITests.dll'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]1 matches
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]1 final results
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]DisableTestImpactAnalysis=undefined
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]Non TIA mode of test execution
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]defaultRoot: '\\Servername\D$\FAF_Applications\Http\XYZAppName\test'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSpecifiedSymbolicLink: 'true'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSymbolicLinks: 'true'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]matchOptions.debug: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nobrace: 'true'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]matchOptions.noglobstar: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]matchOptions.dot: 'true'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]matchOptions.noext: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nocase: 'true'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nonull: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]matchOptions.matchBase: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nocomment: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nonegate: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]matchOptions.flipNegate: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]pattern: '**\*TestAdapter.dll'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]findPath: '\\Servername\D$\FAF_Applications\Http\XYZAppName\test'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]statOnly: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]findPath: '\\Servername\D$\FAF_Applications\Http\XYZAppName\test'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSpecifiedSymbolicLink: 'true'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.8229587Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSymbolicLinks: 'true'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9167061Z ##[debug]306 results
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9167061Z ##[debug]found 306 paths
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9167061Z ##[debug]applying include pattern
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9167061Z ##[debug]adjustedPattern: '\\Servername\D$\FAF_Applications\Http\XYZAppName\test\**\*TestAdapter.dll'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9167061Z ##[debug]1 matches
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9167061Z ##[debug]1 final results
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9167061Z ##[debug]System.Debug=true
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9167061Z ##[warning]vstest.console.exe version does not support the /diag flag. Enable diagnositics via the exe.config files
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9167061Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=warning;]vstest.console.exe version does not support the /diag flag. Enable diagnositics via the exe.config files
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9167061Z ##[debug]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe arg: \\Servername\D$\FAF_Applications\Http\XYZAppName\test\XYZAppName.Nunit.UITests.dll
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9323329Z ##[debug]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe arg: /logger:trx
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9323329Z ##[debug]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe arg: /TestAdapterPath:"D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a"
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9323329Z ##[debug]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe arg: /framework: ".NetFramework,version=V4.7.2"
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9323329Z ##[debug]testing directory 'D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a\TestResults'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9323329Z ##[debug]testing directory 'D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9323329Z ##[debug]mkdir 'D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a\TestResults'
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9323329Z ##[debug]exec tool: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9323329Z ##[debug]Arguments:
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9323329Z ##[debug]   \\Servername\D$\FAF_Applications\Http\XYZAppName\test\XYZAppName.Nunit.UITests.dll
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9323329Z ##[debug]   /logger:trx
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9323329Z ##[debug]   /TestAdapterPath:"D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a"
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9323329Z ##[debug]   /framework:
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9323329Z ##[debug]   .NetFramework,version=V4.7.2
2019-07-18T18:27:43.9323329Z [command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe" \\Servername\D$\FAF_Applications\Http\XYZAppName\test\XYZAppName.Nunit.UITests.dll /logger:trx "/TestAdapterPath:\"D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a\"" /framework: .NetFramework,version=V4.7.2
2019-07-18T18:27:44.0417108Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.9.0
2019-07-18T18:27:44.1198351Z The /Framework argument requires the target .Net Framework version for the test run.   Example:  /Framework:".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1"
2019-07-18T18:27:44.1198351Z The test source file "D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a\.NetFramework,version=V4.7.2" provided was not found.
2019-07-18T18:27:44.1198351Z The test source file "D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a\.NetFramework,version=V4.7.2" provided was not found.
2019-07-18T18:27:44.3854671Z Description: Runs tests from the specified files.
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]rc:1
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]success:false
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[warning]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=warning;]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[error]Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe failed with return code: 1
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe failed with return code: 1
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]defaultRoot: 'D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a\TestResults'
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSpecifiedSymbolicLink: 'true'
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSymbolicLinks: 'true'
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]matchOptions.debug: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nobrace: 'true'
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]matchOptions.noglobstar: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]matchOptions.dot: 'true'
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]matchOptions.noext: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nocase: 'true'
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nonull: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]matchOptions.matchBase: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nocomment: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nonegate: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]matchOptions.flipNegate: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]pattern: 'D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a\TestResults\*.trx'
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]findPath: 'D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a\TestResults'
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]statOnly: 'false'
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]findPath: 'D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a\TestResults'
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSpecifiedSymbolicLink: 'true'
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSymbolicLinks: 'true'
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]  D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a\TestResults (directory)
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]1 results
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]found 1 paths
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]applying include pattern
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]0 matches
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]0 final results
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning;code=002003;]
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[warning]No results found to publish.
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=warning;]No results found to publish.
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[error]Vstest exited with return code: 1.
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Vstest exited with return code: 1.
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4323429Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Vstest exited with return code: 1.
2019-07-18T18:27:44.4479679Z ##[section]Finishing: VsTest - testAssemblies
```

TFS On premise "VS Test" task can't find test assemblies in the Release pipeline. Same tests execute fine in Build pipeline or when invoked locally within server from `Command Prompt`.

1. Test assemblies are identified in the Build pipeline and are copied over to dev environment from build server
2. Test dlls are found in dev server. Test ran successfully from Command Prompt and there are no issues
3. Read/Write access has been granted to everyone
4. Simple 'hello world' test, no need for any package or dependencies

**Error:**

> 2019-07-16T18:46:50.2821329Z ##[warning]No test assemblies found
>   matching the pattern: **\xyz.Nunit.UITests.dll,!**\obj**

What am I missing in my configuration?[Build Defenition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NwjS.png)

**Update based on Suggestion**
1. Added Publish task (Copy task was already there).
[enter image description here][2]

2. The error persists

Comment: Did you publish the assemblies from the build pipeline to the release pipeline?

Comment: Running from a fileshare... I think you'll need to copy over the files to the local agent.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, since build and remote server run test well, this seems related to your configuration of release pipeline.

You are **lacking of artifacts**, you need to add to Build Pipeline **CopyFile** task according to this

> Source folder: $(system.defaultworkingdirectory)
>
> Content : **\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)**
>   **\$(BuildConfiguration)*test*.dll !**\obj**
>
> Target Folder: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)

[image]

Please take a look a look at this similar question here: [Publishing test assemblies with artifacts in order to use them during functional tests on VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527058/publishing-test-assemblies-with-artifacts-in-order-to-use-them-during-functional/51535782#51535782)

[Framework Argument](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvz08.png)
I have added the framework argument in the definition too

Comment: I had the copy task and now added the publish task too. But still the same error

Comment: Please see screen capture in question

Comment: Hi @DeepanDstar You build definition looks no problem, you do not need to add extra "Copy and Publish Build Artifacts" task(which is deprecated) The screenshot is an older sample for your reference.  You just need to use "copy files" and "publish artifact" task.  The whole process:  Get files from sever -- Build the solution --Run the tests -- Copy files -- Publish Artifacts to server (Test Assemblies)    In the Release pipeline, it will **fetch files (Test Assemblies) from Artifacts**, you just need to make sure there are corresponding dlls, then add the same VsTest  task to run it.

Comment: According to your warning info, have you checked your match rule in VSTest task of release? Could it be too  strict for your minimatch patterns which cause azure devops server could not find it?  Besides, since you have mentioned it works well from directly running command in the server. You could also try to use command line task to invoke test instead of vstest task. If all of above is still not working, please share your logs with system.debug=true here. We may need  go through logs to dig into this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrik! I moved one step further. After giving the shared path now the test are matched. But Still the following error message  2019-07-18T17:08:47.4442807Z No test is available in \\<ServerName>\D$\<FolderPath>\xyz.Nunit.UITests.dll. **Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again**.

Comment: @MSFT In other words am I missing any prerequisites in the server. I have vstest.console.exe installed

Comment: @DeepanDstar, According the error log, I found that `The test source file "D:\TFSVSOWork\r45\a\.NetFramework,version=V4.7.2" provided was not found.` It seems you are not install the .net framework 4.7.2 on the that machine, make sure you have install it.

Comment: I ensured that there is .Net framework is installed. Please note that this is our Dev machine and we have other applications installed fine with out any error. Only challenge is with automated testing.Though this is the err message there is something else. May be like a settings I am not aware of. Is there a checklist that would help me.

Comment: @DeepanDstar,  It seems you are not give the correct grammar rule in your parameters, try to use `/Framework:".NetFramework,version=V4.7.2"` instead of `/framework: .NetFramework,version=V4.7.2`. For the details, you can check this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56997328/tfs-prem-release-no-test-assemblies-found-matching-the-pattern-uitests-dll

Comment: Leo Liu Thanks I have added the framework argument in the same manner as prescribed. Please see the question for newly added screen print image of the same.

Comment: Currently log:Date: Starting test execution, please wait...
Date: Logging Vstest Diagnostics in file: \\server\d$\logs\log.txt
Date: NUnit Adapter 3.13.0.0: Test execution started
Date:Running all tests in <Path>\Http\App\test\App.Nunit.dll
Date:    NUnit failed to load <Path>\Http\App\test\App.Nunit.dll
Date:NUnit Adapter 3.13.0.0: Test execution complete
2019-07-26T13:21:36.3841838Z No test is available in \\Server\D$\FAF_Applications\Http\App\test\App.Nunit.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate.

Comment: The issue was because of test agent missing in Release server. The issue is resolved now after adding Deploy test agent task.